# Node console.log: What is "stack: [Getter]"?

Tags: node.js, console.log

I have a response from a soap client library, and when I `console.log` it, I just get "The actual error message"; so I thought it might be a string. However, when I log it using `util.inspect`, it shows me that it's actually an object, more specifically this:

```
{ [Error: The actual error message] stack: [Getter] }
```

What exactly am I getting here, and how do I have to deal with it (get the plain text message)? I've never seen that before, it's obviously not the string I thought it'd be, but it also doesn't look like an object I'm used to.

Edit: I'd now like just to pass the `message` property of the error, but that's not possible for some reason: I can only access it inside the `catch` block.

This is the place where I return the error:

```
// Please note that I've just converted this code from coffeescript
// (and changed it a bit) and most stuff is missing (client is actually defined for example).. 
// But the relevant code to understand what's going on is still in here

Shipping.book = function (information, callback) {
  client.BookQuote(information, function (err, res) {

    var processingError = res.BookQuoteResult.ProcessingError;
    var orderLogString = res.BookQuoteResult.OrderLog.string;

    if (!!processingError && !!orderLogString)
      console.log(orderLogString[0].message) // Doesn't log anything
      callback(orderLogString[0])
  }
}

Shipping.bookSync = function (information) {
  var book;
  book = Meteor.wrapAsync(Shipping.book);
  return book(information);
};
```

And this is where I call the function:

```
var err;

try {
  return Shipping.bookSync(information);
} catch (_error) {
  err = _error;
  console.log(err.message); # Logs the plain text error message
}

// ---
// generated by coffee-script 1.9.2
```

Comment: when you have an instance of Error, you can usually do `console.log(error.stack)` to get a stack trace so that you can figure out where the error was thrown. not quite sure why that is being included in your console.log output though.

Answer (score 1):

The `stack` property of `Error` instances are made as getters because the stack traces are not cheap to generate. So by making it a getter, it lazily creates stack traces only when needed/requested. `util.inspect()` only inspects properties, it does not activate getters/functions/other special types.

If you want to get just the message from an `Error` instance, you can use `error.message` to get the text portion.

Lastly, you can always check the type of a variable with `typeof foo === 'string'` or explicitly check for an `Error` via `foo instanceof Error`.

Comment: Using `error.message` does only work in my `catch` block, but not where I return the error for some reason.

Comment: If you're having that problem, perhaps you should expand a bit in your question, showing more code and what you see in your `catch` block vs. wherever you're receiving the same returned error object.

Answer (score 1):

That's an object which has an extra property on it that Node is not expecting:

```
╭« cdrost@xanadu:~ »                                                                                           
╰→ node
> function id(x) { return x; }
undefined
> id.stuff = [1,2,3]
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
> id
{ [Function: id] stuff: [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
```

So the library you're using is handing you an `Error` object (that is, an object which was constructed by some `function Error(...){...}` expression) which has an extra unexpected property named `stack` which is a list of `Getter` objects (constructed by the `Getter`-named function). In this case it looks like the list only has one `Getter`.

**Edit**: to export the message out of the `catch` block you simply need to store the message. This is a bit of a thorny problem due to some properties of JS that get a bit technical. For example, a `catch` block offers a new *lexical environment* according to the spec, but you can only use it for the error parameter because any `var` statements get hoisted up to the nearest *function scope*, outside of the `catch` block.

What you're doing of setting `err = _error` will indeed get the error out of the `catch` block. However, JavaScript lets you `throw` just about **anything**, including throwing an object which still has external references to it:

```
function trickyError(msg) {
    var err = new Error(msg)
    setTimeout(function () {
        delete err.message;
    }, 1);
    throw err;
}
function example() {
    try {
        trickyError("Something insane happened.");
    } catch (e) {
        // This logs the message properly because JS is single-threaded:
        console.log(e.message); 

        // This usually logs `undefined`, but could maybe in some high-load
        // circumstances log the message properly, if the OS neglects the Node
        // thread for 100ms and the Node setTimeout scheduler doesn't respect
        // their temporal order when handling the two events -- I'm not sure
        // that any standards say that they have to happen in order.
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(e.message);
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

To counter this, do not store `err = _error` but `err = _error.message`. Since JS strings are **immutable**, it doesn't matter that some other piece of code might have a reference to the error message.

Comment: But is it possible to just return the error String where I'm commenting "// Doesn't log anything"? This would be much nicer as I'm returning Strings everywhere else, too

Comment: Yes, `return e.message;` is a valid statement in JavaScript  anywhere where `e` is some type of object with properties; this includes a `catch (e) { ... }` block unless you start doing crazy-but-valid things like `throw null;`